# Enviando duas ou mais request pelo form com ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, laravel

Boa tarde galera, quero saber como consigo enviar mais de uma requisição de um form para o meu Controller para fazer o relacionamento no banco ?

Tenho um relacionamento N:M com Usuário e Grupo, só que quando dou o submit no formulário ele só considera um valor do meu formulário, mas preciso que ele considera dois ou mais valores, basicamente preciso dos ids do grupos que o usuários está relacionado no meu controller, para poder manipular e fazer os relacionamentos. Dei uma pesquisada e acho que consigo fazer pelo ajax usuando JQuery, alguém tem alguma dica ou sabe como posso realizar essa façanha ?

Obrigado pela atenção.

### Formulário

```
<form action="{{ route('postGrupoUsuario') }}" method="post" class="centralizarNomes">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="Usuarios_Lista">Usuarios </label>
        <select name="Usuario" class="form-control Selecionar_Usuario">  
            @foreach($listaUsuario as $usuario)
                <option value="{{ $usuario->Usuario_ID }}"> {{ $usuario->Usuario_Nome }}  </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 65px;" class="text-center">ID</th>
                        <th>Nome do Grupo</th>
                        <th> Selecionar </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($listaGrupo as $grupo)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"> {{$grupo->Grupo_ID }}</td>
                            <td> <span class="font-medium"> {{$grupo->Grupo_Nome }}</span></td>
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="Grupo" id="grupo" value="{{ $grupo->Grupo_ID }}"> </input> </td>
                        </tr> 
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>    
    </div>                                
    <div class="btn_Adc_Cancelar">                                                                              
        <a class="btn btn-inverse waves-effect waves-light"  href="{{ route('indexAdmin') }}" id="btn_cancelar">Cancelar</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10" id="btn_cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

### Controller

```
public function ModelRelacaoPost (Request $request) //Faz o relacionamento
    {   
        $usuario_id = $request->get('Usuario'); //pega o id do usuário
        $grupo_id = $request->get('Grupo');//pego id do grupo

        $usuario = Usuario::find($usuario_id); //encontra com base na pesquisa
        $grupo = Grupo::find($grupo_id);//encontra com base na pesquisa

        $usuario->grupo()->attach($grupo); //faz o relacionamento

        return redirect()->route('grupoUsuario'); //redireciona
    }
```

> Atualmente consigo fazer o relacionamento do Usuário com um Grupo mas
>   não para vários grupos.
>   Estou utilizando Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você deverá colocar o token nas meta tags na head para recuperar as informações via ajax

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

depois configure o ajax global com o token

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

agora você precisa definir a submissão via ajax para o formulário

```
$('form.centralizarNomes').on('submit',function(formEvent){
    formEvent.preventDefault(); //removendo ação submit;
             $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: window.getRoute('cadastranomes'), // ira ficar /api/form/cadastranomes
            dataType:'json',
            data: $(this).serialize() })
            .done(function(response) {
                //console.log(response);
                //resposta
            })
            .fail(function() { console.log("error"); })
            .always(function() { console.log("complete"); });
    })
return false; // para não redirecionar a página;

});
```

//recomendo você criar uma função do tipo na header assim você cria uma rota prefixo, assim você pode chamar a url do ajax em um arquivo javascript
depois se tiver que alterar a url da sua rota não precisa alterar todo seu javascript

```
window.getRoute = function (url) {
            var apiCall = '/api/form/'+url;
            return apiCall;
}
```

espero ter ajudado

obs no controller será necessário configurar a resposta como json

no controller você pega seus inputs pelo request da mesma forma não irá mudar nada apenas a requisição via ajax

Comment: Mano eu tenho que passa a minha rota completa ou só a rota do post ?

Comment: vc pode colocar a função get route ou usar direto na requisição
substitua  
url: window.getRoute('cadastranomes'),
por 
 url: '/api/form/cadastranomes,